# Add external library into current c++ project

Tags: c++, r, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm trying to use the xgboost library to basically translate a model I developed in R to C++.
I've not used an external library and other sources online did not help me much so decided to ask the question here to hopefully find the way to do it.

Here's the library I need to use in my C++ code: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. I have a make file that I use to define my project.

I am looking for the proper way to use this library in my C++ code.
If you have ever used this library before, I really appreciate your help. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: what compilation system are you using? I personally prefer [cmake](http://cmake.org) , for typical cpp, you will need to compile and then link to that library

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I use Cmake as well. By linking do you mean just adding the search paths to the cmake file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the way to resolve this issue. I shared it in another answer
[Add an external library (e.g., Eigen) via CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999915/add-an-external-library-e-g-eigen-via-cmake)

Hope this helps people who are looking!

Answer (score 0):

To use the library, one needs to first build it. I could not manage to build the master branch. So, I decided to use the V0.4 instead. I built the solution in that branch using Visual Studio and it produced the dll and lib files. One can then import the .dll file by using Add_library to add it via Cmake. After Add_library, the include directories need to be added by include_directories command.

I need to generate .a and .so files in the end. I'm working in windows and could not find a way to generate these files, yet!